# Sanitize User Input in C# - Cleanest Way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, overloading, sanitize

There's a gotcha when inserting img's dynamically via scripts.

Take the following code to insert a image for a place:

```
newPlace.find('.PlaceThumb').append('<img src="' + place.ThumbnailUrl + '" alt="' + place.Name + '" width="50px" style = "padding:2px;"/>');
```

Someone could name their place: " onload="alert('hi')" and the tag would get rendered as:

```
<img src="/item.aspx?id=123" alt="" onload="alert('hi')" width="50px" style = "padding:2px;"/>
```

When the image is loaded, the script will execute.

While only  and  tags support the onload attribute, this is a good lesson to never trust user input.

What is the "Correct" (nice, elegant, clean, general) way of doing this:

```
newPlace.find('.PlaceThumb').append('<img src="' + place.ThumbnailUrl + '" alt="' + place.Name.replace('"', '&quot;') + '" width="50px" style = "padding:2px;"/>');
```

I was thinking maybe with templates you could define an operator on strings that would UUencode them - similar to how a string prefixed with @ in C# has special meaning vis a vis backslashes. Is there a way to add this functionality to the standard .net string class?

Comment: btw - upon further research it looks like the @ is a compiler-level syntactic sugar that only works on string literals.

Comment: The code is not C# code - looks like javascript.

Comment: This is about XSS prevention. One thing to think about: restrict user input to alpha-numerical characters on the client-side with javascript and on the server side validate by removing all non-alphanumerical characters from the input string.

Comment: The string sanitization happens server side in C#.

Comment: I believe all sanitization should happen server-side. Otherwise you can fiddle your HTTP responses.

Comment: It is not clear _what_ string is sanitized and when - before the javascript generates this or after? Is it the `place.ThumbnailUrl` or the whole line?

Comment: newPlace.find('.PlaceThumb').append('<img src="' + place.ThumbnailUrl + '" alt="' + place.Name + '" width="50px" style = "padding:2px;"/>'); Executes server-side in C#. It renders HTML into the response like PHP echo.

Comment: I can see how that could be confusing I should have been more explicit. I'm not a JS jockey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't tell if you're using jQuery or not. If you are, then you can do something like this:

```
newPlace.find('.PlaceThumb').append('<img>');
$('.PlaceThumb img').attr('src', place.ThumbnailUrl).attr('alt', place.Name);
```

That may not be valid, it's just off the top of my head, but should give you something to look into.

Comment: The question is tagged "C#" and "asp.net"

Comment: @RickNZ - yes, but that is clearly Javascript.  You can tell by the single quotes, they don't make strings in C#.

Comment: Yes, but the JavaScript is being generated from C# (at least that's my interpretation; the question is a little ambiguous, I admit).

Answer (score 0):

[AntiXSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) is one possible solution. Be very carefull with encoding as your code seem to have large number of layers between data and rendered HTML (ASP.Net -> renders HTML template as part of rendered JavaScript -> Browser loads JavaScript -> something executes the scriot that in turn uses JQuery to create HTML based on the temeplate).

Note: Consider separating CSS (width and style attributes) from HTML layout as good HTML practice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use new Uri( yourUrlString ). I believe using that (alog with the methods IsWellFormedUriString and IsWellFormedOriginalString) will help you validate the input.